# filtering certain email addresses from same domain in Gmail

Tags: regex, email, gmail, filtering

Filter email address with regular expressions: I am new to regular expressions and was hoping someone might be able to help out.

I am trying to pattern match an email address string with the following format:

abc12@domain.edu

I want to filter for localized address pattern that has 3 letters followed by 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2}@domain.edu
```

Comment: Thanks much. I've tried it. It doesn't seem to catch old emails with that pattern.